# Why is my Hero (not Leader) surviving when s/he falls in battle and I win the battle?

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

I am playing Age of Wonders 3 for the first time and I am in normal difficulty on the second mission, Promised Lands, of the campaign. I'm taking my time with it and trying to understand all the minutiae involved and one phenomenon I can't seem to find an explanation for is really confusing me. When I fight a battle involving one of my Heros (Sundren, Nomlik or Groshak) if the Hero dies on the tactical map but I win the combat they don't die, they just show back up on the strategic map as if they didn't die. My normal units die as normal and if my leader (Reskar) falls he needs to take the normal amount of turns to respawn, but my Hero's never die. Any explanation?

Answer (score 2):

There is a passive ability called `Resurgence`. Units with `Resurgence` will respawn at the end of combat, if you were victorious.

Reading about it, it seems that they added an option to the game to enable `Resurgence` to all heroes automatically. This was to address a common complaint that having heroes die permanently was a bit too harsh. Without it, you could fight a huge battle, do very well, but make one mistake near the end and lose your hero. Even though you won the battle it's still really a heavy loss to have lost your hero, possibly even forcing you to reload the game and fight the battle all over again. (There's also a similar with auto-calcing fights.)

When your hero has `Resurgence`, you can then fight with him without worry, and even if he happens to die because you over extended him, as long as you win the battle he'll revive.